# How to get verbose when running bash script

Tags: bash

When I run the command directly I get the details related to downloading. but while running via bash script I don't get it. Is there any way to do this?

```
91981@DESKTOP-QAU8JAM MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ youtube-dl -o "STATS/XGBoost_Part_2@_Classification.mp4" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU
```

---

```
[youtube] 8b1JEDvenQU: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: STATS\XGBoost_Part_2@_Classification.mp4
[download] 100% of 43.28MiB in 00:14
```

**b.sh:**

```
title=$(youtube-dl --get-title https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU | tr ' ' '_' | tr ':' '@')
echo "$title"

mkdir -p STATS
l=$(youtube-dl -o "STATS/$title.mp4" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b1JEDvenQU)
```

---

I get this:

```
$ bash b.sh
XGBoost_Part_2@_Classification
```

Comment: sooo `echo "$l"`? So why did you `l=$( ... )` ? Just remove it and run the command.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I just started learning bash scripting so I was not aware of that. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: `$(...)` runs the command and captures its output, that's why you don't see anything.